# python sys.stdin for loop not working

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to write a simple program that will read from keyboard as sys.stdin.readline()

I am trying to do it in a 'for' loop as

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin.readline().strip("\n"):
if(line == 'stop'):
    break
print(line)
```

Problem is 
1) The for loop is not executing. It exits after first input
2) the if-statement is not getting hit when input is stop
3)if I input "hi" and hit ctrl+D I see output as
"H"
"I"

I can achieve my goal by a while loop as shown below BUT how to do it in For loop ?

```
 import sys
 def readfromconsole():
new_list = []
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip("\n")
    if(line == 'enough'):
        break
    else:

        new_list.append(line)
print(new_list)
return
print("Welcome")
print("please enter your input, enough to stop")
readfromconsole()
```

Answer (score 0):

It stops after the first interation because you are assigning the value being iterated over in the definition of the for loop. You can see this by doing 
`sys.stdin.readline()` in the interpreter. This means your loop is equivalent to

```
for line in <first entered line>:
    do things
```

In your while loop, it will keep asking for more inputs, and so your code works.

Comment: so there is no way to read from keyboard using only for loop ? other than using input() ?